# Application or object defined error on update macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have the following code that is supposed to compare two sheets and update the first one with the information of the second. However, I have an "Application defined or object defined error" that I don't know how to fix on this part of the code : `Sheets("LAT - Master Data").Range(Cells(Ligne, "E"), Cells(Ligne, "AS")).Copy Sheets("Launch Tracker").Cells(Lig, "E")`

I have tried to figure out why it is not working however when I check the variables are correct... Would someone have a clue why this is happening ?

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Dim Ttrak_concat, Tdata_concat, Derlig As Integer

Sub mettre_a_jour()
Dim Cptr As Integer, D_concat As Object, Ref As String, Ligne As Integer, Lig As Integer
Dim Start As Single
Dim test 'pour essais
    Start = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call concatener("LAT - Master Data", Tdata_concat)
    Call concatener("Launch Tracker", Ttrak_concat)

    'creation d'une collection: concaténation - ligne dans tracker
    Set D_concat = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Cptr = 1 To UBound(Ttrak_concat)
    Ref = Ttrak_concat(Cptr, 1)
        If Not D_concat.exists(Ref) Then: D_concat.Add Ref, Ttrak_concat(Cptr, 2)
    Next

    'comparaison entre les feuilles
    For Cptr = 1 To UBound(Tdata_concat)
        Ref = Tdata_concat(Cptr, 1) 'chaineIPR feuil data
        Ligne = Tdata_concat(Cptr, 2) 'localisation feuil data
        If D_concat.exists(Ref) Then
                Lig = D_concat.Item(Ref) 'localisation feuil track
        Else
                Lig = Derlig + 1
        End If
        Sheets("LAT - Master Data").Range(Cells(Ligne, "E"), Cells(Ligne, "AS")).Copy Sheets("Launch Tracker").Cells(Lig, "E")

                Next
    Sheets("Launch Tracker").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MsgBox "mise à jour réalisée en: " & Round(Timer - Start, 2) & " secondes"


End Sub

'---------------------------------------
Sub concatener(Feuille, Tablo)
Dim T_coli, T_colp, T_colr, Cptr As Integer
Dim test
 With Sheets(Feuille)
        'mémorisation des colonnes I P R
        Derlig = .Columns("H").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        T_coli = Application.Transpose(.Range("H3:H" & Derlig))
        T_colp = Application.Transpose(.Range("O3:O" & Derlig))
        T_colr = Application.Transpose(.Range("Q3:Q" & Derlig))
        'concatène les données IPR pour comparaison
        ReDim Tablo(UBound(T_colr), 2)
        For Cptr = 1 To UBound(T_colr)
           Tablo(Cptr, 1) = T_coli(Cptr) & " " & T_colp(Cptr) & " " & T_colr(Cptr)
           Tablo(Cptr, 2) = Cptr + 2 'ligne de la concaténation
       Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: First suspect is the unreferenced `Cells` that will use the active sheet as source. If the active sheet is not "LAT - Master Data" it will fail. The error in that case should be something like "Method Range of worksheet class failed" though. Fix it be specifying the sheet or build a string for the range (i.e. `"E" & Ligne & ":AS" & Ligne`)

Comment: @arcadeprecinct thank you so much ! It was actually the ladder. It works wonders !

Comment: great, I posted an answer how to specify the sheet and how to copy the values without using `.Copy` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells(Ligne, "E")` and  `Cells(Ligne, "AS")` refer to cells on the active sheet since you didn't specify a sheet. If the active sheet is not "LAT - Master Data" you will receive an error because you cant use cells on one sheet to specify a range on another. To fix it, specify the sheet for the `Cells` or use a string:

```
With Sheets("LAT - Master Data")
    .Range(.Cells(Ligne, "E"), .Cells(Ligne, "AS")).Copy Sheets("Launch Tracker").Cells(Lig, "E")
End With
```

or

```
Sheets("LAT - Master Data").Range("E" & Ligne & ":AS" & Ligne).Copy Sheets("Launch Tracker").Cells(Lig, "E")
```

My favorite would be to skip the copying altogether (if you don't need to copy formatting or formulas):

```
Sheets("Launch Tracker").Range("E" & Ligne & ":AS" & Ligne).Values = Sheets("LAT - Master Data").Range("E" & Ligne & ":AS" & Ligne).Values
```